# I would like to make a trail in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to get a very secure trail in vb.net, I watched some totorials but it is easy to hack it, Because if the user change the system date the trail checker is not working because it reads date and time from the system.

Comment: And what stops you to make it?

Comment: Presumably you mean "trial" rather than "trail". There's no simple way to do it yourself. You either have to use a proper licensing component, spend lots of time writing and testing your own code or make do with something very basic. Whichever option you choose, it's not a question for SO. We don't recommend third-party tools or write your code for you.  You need to do the research, make the best attempt you can at whichever option you choose and then post here when you encounter a specific issue.